# IQueriable<T> for objects with better than O(n) performance?

Tags: linq-to-objects, iqueryable

Are there any IQueriable implementaions for linq-to-objects that perform better than the default O(n) linear search performance that you get when calling myEnumerable.AsQueriable()?

I've had a look at http://www.codeplex.com/i4o/ which has better performance, but seems to rely on using extension methods on IndexedCollection rather than making IndexedColleciton implement IQueriable.

I'm keen to keep my interface returning IQueriable<T> as I don't want anyone to know whether they are hitting a cache or a db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inherently, any querying of a non-indexed resource (such as a list or IEnumerable) is going to be at best O(n) because it has to iterate through every item in the list to check the condition. To achieve performance better than O(n) you need to look into indexing the data in some form.

As you mentioned, you probably want to look at a library to wrap up creating these indexes, especially if you want to only expose IQueryable.

If you were interested in a more manual way of looking up data with better performance, then I'd suggest looking at dictionaries for doing efficient lookups by key, or possibly using b-trees if you need to do range queries. [Here's a nice MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379572%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) post on data structures including b-trees if you're interested in the theory behind it. Also, [NGenerics](http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/) might be an interesting project to look at.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to have a look at plinq http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx

Comment: True, but in many ways parallelisation is a last resort (with throw more hardware at it) - if I can index the properties I'm linqing on then we should be able to get one / two orders of magnitude improvement by using a IQueriable backed by a less naive datastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer might be to back it by an in memory object database like: [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/s/linqdb.aspx)